# Disable an account using WMI

Tags: c#, wmi

I am trying to disable a local Windows account. With the aid of the Microsoft librairy, I was able to write this

```
ManagementScope mgmtScope = new ManagementScope("\\\\.\\Root\\CIMv2");
ObjectQuery oQuery = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_UserAccount");
ManagementObjectSearcher mgmtSearch = new ManagementObjectSearcher(mgmtScope, oQuery);
ManagementObjectCollection objCollection = mgmtSearch.Get();
foreach (ManagementObject mgmtObject in objCollection)
{
    if ((string)mgmtObject["Name"] == "test")
    {
        mgmtObject.SetPropertyValue("Disabled", true);
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", mgmtObject.GetPropertyValue("Disabled"));
    }
}
```

The `GetPropertyValue` function tells me that the value has been set to "true" but when the program exits the loop foreach, the value is set again to "false".

Does anyone know why this happens?

EDIT: I finaly found the answer. I just needed to apply the changes to the object with the method `ManagementObject.Put()`

Comment: Nice work! If you'd like, you can actually answer your own question and provide the information you found in the answer. It makes it a little easier for future readers to find the answer, if anyone else runs across the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the changes to the object with the method

```
ManagementObject.Put()
```

Answer (score 0):

This question already has an answer but I will take my liberty to show you how much easier you can do that with [ORMi](https://github.com/nicoriff/ORMi) library (which I made and mantain):

1) Define your class:

```
[WMIClass("Win32_UserAccount")]
public class UserAccount
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Disabled { get; set; }
}
```

2) Query WMI:

```
WMIHelper helper = new WMIHelper("root\\CimV2");

UserAccount account = helper.Query<UserAccount>().Where(p => p.Name == "test").SingleOrDefault();

account.Disabled = false;

helper.UpdateInstance(account);
```

Hope it helps!.

PD: You can also install via [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ORMi/)